# Different offsets in listbox using .Find and if statements vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a listbox in a userform where I show searches from a database. I have 14 columns in the database I want to be able to search for information. So I have a textbox I use for searching and a listbox to view the results as the textbox changes. Here is the code I have as of now:

```
With ARK_database.Range("A:AS")
    Dim rng2Find As Range
    Dim strFirstFind As String

    lstLookup.Clear

    If Not kritLookup.Text = "" Then
        Set rng2Find = .Find(kritLookup.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rng2Find Is Nothing Then
            strFirstFind = rng2Find.Address

            Column = rng2Find.Column
            Do
                If Column = 1 Then
                    If rng2Find.Row > 1 Then
                        lstLookup.AddItem rng2Find.Value 'RefNr
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 1) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 3) 'navn
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 2) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 1) 'dato
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 3) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 4) 'varsler navn
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 4) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 6) 'varlser adr
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 5) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 5) 'varsler tlf
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 6) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 7) 'varsler zip
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 7) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 8) 'varsler sted
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 8) = rng2Find.Offset(0, 9) 'region
                     End If
                End If
                If Column = 43 Then
                     If rng2Find.Row > 1 Then
                        lstLookup.AddItem rng2Find.Value 'nettstasjon
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 1) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -42) 'refnr
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 2) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -41) 'dato
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 3) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -39) 'reg av
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 4) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -36) 'adr feil
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 5) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -4) 'avg
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 6) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -38) 'varsler
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 7) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -21) 'kat
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 8) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -33) 'region
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 9) = rng2Find.Offset(0, -18) 'beskrivelse
                    End If
                End If

                Set rng2Find = .FindNext(rng2Find)
            Loop While Not rng2Find Is Nothing And rng2Find.Address <> strFirstFind
        End If
    Else
        lstLookup.Clear
    End If

 End With
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how to sort the findings using .Find, I assume using a For Each would be easier, but a lot slower. I want all the results to show in the same listbox, but with the offset correct. Is there a better way of doing this? Or some way to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: `.Find` is for finding things and not used for sorting. So, I don't quite understand what you mean / want.Yet, if you have a database backend (possibly understanding SQL) then I'd rather ask the database to do the grouping / sorting / finding before showing the result in your ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. This is what I ended up with

```
Private Sub cmd_lookup_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ARK_database.Activate
With ARK_database.Range("A:AS")
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Tomorrow As Date
    Tomorrow = Date + 1

    Dim rng2Find As Range
    Dim strFirstFind As String
    Dim KritLookupFind As Range

    lstLookup.Clear

    If Not kritLookup.Text = "" Then
        Set rng2Find = .Find(kritLookup.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

        'if value found then set a variable for the address
        If Not rng2Find Is Nothing Then
            strFirstFind = rng2Find.Address

            Column = rng2Find.Column

            If Column = 1 Or Column = 2 Or Column = 4 Or Column = 5 Or Column = 6 Or Column = 7 Or Column = 20 Or Column = 21 Or Column = 22 Or Column = 31 Or Column = 34 Or Column = 39 Or _
            Column = 43 Or Column = 45 Then
               Do
                    If rng2Find.Row > 1 Then
                        sjekkVariabel = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Value
                        For i = 0 To lstLookup.ListCount - 1
                            If lstLookup.List(i) = sjekkVariabel Then
                                GoTo LastLine
                            End If
                        Next i
                        lstLookup.AddItem Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Value 'RefNr
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 1) 'dato
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 42) 'NS
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 20) 'kommune
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 21) 'komponent
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 4) 'kunde navn
                        lstLookup.List(lstLookup.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(rng2Find.Row, 1).Offset(0, 24) 'beskrivelse
                    End If
                    'find the next address to add
LastLine:
                    Set rng2Find = .FindNext(rng2Find)
                Loop While Not rng2Find Is Nothing And rng2Find.Address  <> strFirstFind
            End If

                Set rng2Find = .FindNext(rng2Find)
        End If
        Else
            lstLookup.Clear
    End If
End With
End Sub
```